# What privileges do I gain with each addition step of the license (in the UK?)

Tags: license, united-kingdom

The UK has 3 licensing levels, foundation, intermediate and advanced. Aside from the allowed power output going up each time (10W, 50W, 400W) are there any other privileges one would gain?

Comment: Just noticed, after 10 years... Inter are 50W not 100W ;-)

Comment: @AndrewM0YMA Oops, thanks - sorted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I'm a mere Foundation Licence holder, but other than the increased power, no extra privileges open up at Intermediate Level - it is only with the Advanced/Full Licence that the extras arrive

Mostly these around Notice of Variations to hold [Special Event calls](http://rsgb.org/main/operating/licensing-novs-visitors/special-event-stations/) and/or operate Club callsigns and/or to [set up and run a repeater](http://rsgb.org/main/operating/licensing-novs-visitors/other-nov/) - and to operate on some extra bands (eg LF and 5MHz)

Foundation and Intermediate licensees cannot operate Special Event or Club Calls except under supervision, and cannot operate on LF or 5MHz.

The other bonus for Advanced Licencees (not available to Foundation of Intermediates) is to operate as Maritime Mobile (at sea) or overseas ([under CEPT reciprocal terms](http://rsgb.org/main/operating/licensing-novs-visitors/operating-abroad/))

--
Edit: At the time of writing the first sentence was correct... but within seven months of that post, I'd progressed through the Intermediate to the Full Licence... but the answer still holds!

Comment: There are a couple of extra privileges I've since become aware of at intermediate level - the ability to design / build your own amateur radio circuits (foundation just lets you build pre-designed kits) and the option to apply to become a foundation level practical assessor.